# Basic Error with my Basic Code, invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Thanks to everyone who helped me out with this problem. Greatly appreciate all the assistance; the code was fine I just had something wrong on my side with the IDLE.

```
#Anthony Williams
#Restaurant Bill Source Code
#Prompts user for the cost of food and drinks (Input)
#The total that needs to be paid (Output)


def main():
    # Intro
    print("Restaurant Bill Generator ...")
    print()

    # Initialized Constants
    tip_amount = 0.18
    tax_amount = 0.075

    # Prompts user for the cost of food and drink
    food_expenses = float(input("Please enter how much you spent on food:"))
    drink_expenses = float(input("Please enter how much you spent on drinks: "))

    print("Restaurant Bill")

    # Calculating Cost of Meal
    meal_cost = food_expenses + drink_expenses

    # Calculating the tax (7.5% in decimal form is 0.075)
    tax = meal_cost * tax_amount

    # Getting the subtotal
    subtotal = meal_cost + tax

    # Calculating the tip amount (18% is 0.18 in decimal form)
    tip = subtotal * tip_amount

    # Calculating the total
    total = meal_cost + tax + tip

    print("Your meal cost is", meal_cost)
    print("Tax collected is", tax)
    print("The amount tipped is", tip)
    print("Your final total is", total)

main()
```

I'm running my code, but it gives me an error.

[image: The Error]

I tried looking at examples, but still didn't work. So, I'm not sure what to do please help.

The purpose of the code was to write a program that prompts the user for the cost of a meal (food and drinks) consumed at a restaurant and produces a bill detailing tax, tip, and total amounts. The tax is 7.5% of the meal (food and drinks) cost. The tip should be 18% of the subtotal after adding the tax.

I believe I missed a significant detail, by the way, I am using Python newest download, 3.11.3 (Not sure, if this may be contributing to the problem)

Edit: 30-40 minutes later, I added some new code.

> #Anthony Williams
> #Restaurant Bill Source Code
> #Prompts user for the cost of food and drinks (Input)
> #The total that needs to be paid (Output)
>
> def main():
>
> ```
> # Intro
> print("Restaurant Bill Generator ...")
> print()
>
> # Initialized Constants
> tip_amount = 0.18
> tax_amount = 0.075
>
> # Prompts user for the cost of food and drink
> food_expenses = float(input("Please enter how much you spent on food: "))
> drink_expenses = float(input("Please enter how much you spent on drinks: "))
>
> print("Restaurant Bill")
>
> # Calculating Cost of Meal
> meal_cost = food_expenses + drink_expenses
>
> # Calculating the tax (7.5% in decimal form is 0.075)
> tax = meal_cost * tax_amount
>
> # Getting the subtotal
> subtotal = meal_cost + tax
>
> # Calculating the tip amount (18% is 0.18 in decimal form)
> tip = subtotal * tip_amount
>
> # Calculating the total
> total = meal_cost + tax + tip
>
> print("Your meal cost is", meal_cost)
> print("Tax collected is", tax)
> print("The amount tipped is", tip)
> print("Your final total is", total)
>
>
> # Additional Lines
> print("Thank you for coming here, we hope you enjoy.")
> print()
> ```
>
> **m**ain() SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The lowercase m is highlighted as an invalid syntax error. I don't know what that means. I kept my original code up at the top in case this may be an error and doesn't work for anybody else.

Comment: Don't use `eval()` to convert input to a number, use `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: Code runs perfectly fine for me. Have you tried refreshing whatever you're running this in?

Comment: Yes, Barmar. I converted food_expenses eval into float(), so it now looks like this food_expenses = float(input("Please enter how much you spent on food: "))
It still didn't work, however. I also did the same for drink expenses.

Comment: Yes, B Remmelzwaal. I have multiple times, I used those online scanners to see if there were any syntax errors they could identify, but it said the code was correct. I may try reinstalling Python.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams That wasn't meant as a fix to the problem, just general Python advice. I suspect there's an invisible character on the line before `main()`

Comment: Copy'n'paste of the code in the question reveals no syntax errors. Don't use eval() like that

Comment: Is there any way to remove the assumed invisible character? I'm very new to Python, so I'm not sure how to identify and remove it.

Comment: This code works on copy/paste. copy and paste into notepad and look for unintentional spaces. Remember in python, indentation is treated as inputs.

Comment: @DarkKnight, I changed the eval to float. However, it still gives me the same error. I edited my post to reflect the code accurately and copied and pasted it into Python.

Comment: You can set your IDE to show non printable characters. Maybe you've got spaces instead of a tabulation or vice versa. Python is pretty picky about that.

Comment: @Adhd Data scientist, to respond to your comment, I been looking at my notepad for any indentation mistakes and spaces. However, I think it matched up so I don't think it was an indentation error or mistakes space error. I may be wrong though, however I'm limited on time since I have to submit this in relatively, 2 hours and 30 minutes.

Comment: @Gameplay, how do you set up your IDE to show nonprintable characters?

Comment: let's go back to the basics: HOW are you running this code? What command do you use? What environment do you use (Command line? IDLE? Some other IDE)?

Comment: Depends on the IDE, I'd look for something like "view" "editor"  or something like that

Comment: @MrE, I'm using IDLE Shell 3.11.3. I essentially open it copy and paste it; what you see in my post is me copying and pasting it into IDLE Shell 3.11.3, hitting enter, and then the syntax error popping up highlighting the error.

Comment: @Gameplay, yeah I think I don't have those options, I probably would need to add more code in finding nonprintable characters. However, I have no clue how to do that and think that's way more advanced in what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It is working for me without any problem, You mentioned that you copy pasted the code so check that the indentation is consistent like if it's tab keep only tabs, also for whitespaces if its 4 whitespace use 4 whitespace everwhere for the indentations

Comment: try adding more lines between the function definition and the `main()`. Or better yet, put that in a proper main clause like this `if __name__ == '__main__': main()`. The typical number of lines between function definitions is 2 blank lines, according to pycharm.

Comment: @Mohammed Safvan, I used indent region, and indent width to 4.  Didn't work, and I indented everything with space again to see if that would work, but it didn't. Not sure, why it's not working for me when everybody else has tried it, and worked. Everyone is assuming it's an indentation problem, which is a very high possibility. However, my indentantion feels consistent.

Comment: Try opening a new notepad window. Copy the text from this post to the notepad. Then from notepad save the file as `test.py` and then run the `test.py` file directly. Maybe your IDLE is causing the issue somehow.

Comment: @iggy12345, thank you for the suggestion. However, it's related to a school assignment so I can't really add something we haven't learned yet. I tried adding additional lines, it gave me a different error. main() The program highlights m, I will be editing my post to reflect this.
Syntax error: Invalid syntax

Comment: @Squarish What you said, I just recently tried and after inputting the two values like requested. The test.py closes out on its own. It doesn't display the print/output.

Comment: I think you are trying to double-click on the python file. Don't do that. When you double-click, the terminal closes when the program ends. So it displays the output and closes before you can look at it. Instead, open a terminal yourself. Browse to the location of the file. Then run `python test.py`.

Comment: You can open a terminal in a folder by typing `cmd` and hit the [enter] key on the address bar of the terminal.

Comment: @Squarish, thank you that seemed to work you taught me something new. Greatly appreciated that seems to work. Like, you said I think the result is that there's something wrong with my IDLE.

Comment: as another suggestion, you could just take the code out of the function and just run it directly without nesting it in the function, that may work

Comment: @iggy12345, yes that also seemed to work. I was using the main() function though, however as it was requested by my teacher.

Comment: I'm going to assume that the issue here stems from the fact that IDLE is a bit of a mess, I'd suggest using any other interpreter instead

Comment: @iggy12345 why do you say IDLE is a mess? I've used it for many years, and except for locking up when you try to display something too large it's been excellent.

Comment: idk, it sure seems like it, you just listed another bug, on top of the one revealed in this post... If an IDE has fundamental issues when running basic code that is valid in the language, then it's a mess